# Nikon D3100 Squeaky Lens Problems?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d3100

I've been using my Nikon D3100 and it all worked fine, until today, I tried to take a picture and pushed the button and started making a noise like the lens was working when I had it set to Manual I do everything, focus manually, zoom out/in, push the button and start hearing those noises... I removed the lens, thinking I could be the camera, but for my surprise it works fine, push the button and capture an image (bad one, since it was functioning without the lens) but it had no problem at all... Then I tried again to put it back and the same noises... Like a "squeaky" noise sort of when you try to start a car by accelerating but the engine doesn't work...

Note: It's the lens that came with the camera...

I'll appreciate any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

The high pitched squeak you are hearing, is most likely coming from the AF motors in the Lens.
Nikon budget and kit lenses have been known for this issue for many years.

From what I know, very rarely do these squeaks actually affect the AF performance and in the over whelming majority of cases, people have lived with these squeaks for years and just become accustom to them.

In the past, having the entire AF Motor replaced seemed to be the only solution, however, today any Nikon authorised repair centre should be able to repair and polish the AF motor and get rid of the squeak. It is also worth searching for independent camera service centres as they may do the job for a lot less money.

Please also note, Nikon has a Factory Standards chart, and if the squeak falls within this acceptable chart, then they can refuse to repair.

The final decision depends on the photographer; if you are are happy with the AF performance and cannot see any other impeding factor, then you need to weigh up the cost of repair against the elimination of the squeak.